# How to list all the cousins of a person in a binary tree

Tags: python, sorting, data-structures, binary-tree, abstract-data-type

Given a list of names, ages, and children of members of a family (each of which has at most 2 children), I want to identify the names of all the cousins of particular family member.

I have created this binary tree ADT to create a family tree:

```
def make_empty_tree():
    return ("btree",[])

def makeTree(root,left,right):
    return ("btree",[root,left,right])

def root(tree):
    return tree[1][0]

def left_subtree(tree):
    return tree[1][1]

def right_subtree(tree):
    return tree[1][2]

def is_empty_tree(tree):
    return tree[1] == []

def is_btree(tree):
    return tree[0] == "btree"

def is_leaf_tree(tree):
    left = left_subtree(tree)
    right = right_subtree(tree)
    return is_empty_tree(left) and is_empty_tree(right)
```

Unfortunately, I haven't done classes yet so I don't yet have the flexibility of using those in my implementation.

The function `cousins(p, people)` takes two parameters: `p` the name of the person I need to find the cousins for and a list of lists `people` containing family members' name, age, and a list of their children. The information of a parent is always given before that of the children. If a person has no children the list containing children is allowed to be an empty list.

Sample data:

```
p = 'Tom'

people = [['George', 75, ['Bob', 'Vicky']],['Bob', 48, ['Tom', 'Sophie']], ['Vicky', 42, ['Karen']], ['Tom', 23, []], ['Sophie', 21, []], ['Karen', 19, []]]
```

Sample output:

```
>>> cousins(p, people)
>>> ['Karen']
```

The output list of cousins should be sorted by youngest first. Where cousins are of the same age, they should be ordered in alphabetic order.

Comment: How do you propose to express family relationships with a binary tree, when every child must have two parents?

Comment: My tree is only required to show one parent per group of children.

Answer (score 0):

So a cousin the the parent's sibling's child. For example, given this tree:

```
                       ggp
                   gp1      gp
                p1   p2   p    p
              c1  c c  c c c  c c

ggp = great grandparent
gp = grandparent
p = parent
c = child
```

Now, let's say that you want to find the cousins (there will be at most two) for the node marked "c1".

The cousins are the children of the node marked "p2". To find them, you need to find the parent's parent ("gp1"), take that node's other child, and then output that node's children.

To do this, do an inorder traversal of the tree to find the family member you want to get cousins for. When you find that node, the parent and grandparent (and every other node in the hierarchy above) is available on the call stack. You can return the parent and grandparent when you unwind the stack.

Given the grandparent and parent, you can easily select the grandparent's other child (parent's sibling), and from there get its children (the cousins).

Comment: Thanks for making it a little clearer to me. I will see now how I can code this.

Answer (score 0):

Given a list of names, ages, and children of members of a family (each of which has at most 2 children), I want to identify the names of all the cousins of particular family member.

I have created this binary tree ADT to create a family tree:

```
def make_empty_tree():
    return ("btree",[])

def makeTree(root,left,right):
    return ("btree",[root,left,right])

def root(tree):
    return tree[1][0]

def left_subtree(tree):
    return tree[1][1]

def right_subtree(tree):
    return tree[1][2]

def is_empty_tree(tree):
    return tree[1] == []

def is_btree(tree):
    return tree[0] == "btree"

def is_leaf_tree(tree):
    left = left_subtree(tree)
    right = right_subtree(tree)
    return is_empty_tree(left) and is_empty_tree(right)
```

Unfortunately, I haven't done classes yet so I don't yet have the flexibility of using those in my implementation.

The function `cousins(p, people)` takes two parameters: p the name of the person I need to find the cousins for and a list of lists people containing family members' name, age, and a list of their children. The information of a parent is always given before that of the children. If a person has no children the list containing children is allowed to be an empty list.

Sample data:

```
p = 'Tom'

people = [['George', 75, ['Bob', 'Vicky']],['Bob', 48, ['Tom', 'Sophie']], ['Vicky', 42, ['Karen']], ['Tom', 23, []], ['Sophie', 21, []], ['Karen', 19, []]]
```

Sample output:

```
>>> cousins(p, people)
>>> ['Karen']
```

The output list of cousins should be sorted by youngest first. Where cousins are of the same age, they should be ordered in alphabetic order.

MY CODE SO FAR: I WANT HELP TOO

```
def cousins(p, people):
    t=makeTree("Brown",makeTree("chad",makeTree("kirk",make_empty_tree(),make_empty_tree()),makeTree("margon",make_empty_tree(),make_empty_tree())),makeTree("stacy",makeTree("simone",make_empty_tree(),make_empty_tree()),make_empty_tree()))
    return root(left_subtree(right_subtree(t)))
```